# Is this the efficient way to display list of timers constantly updating the UI?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I am displaying a list of timers which constantly update the UI (every one second) to show proper time.
Is this the efficient way ? How this process can be improved from performance point of view ?
I am using MVVMLight toolkit for windows phone.

XAML code:

```
<ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding TimersCollection}" 
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SingleItemTemplate}"/>
```

Here is my simple itemtemplate code,It also has Pause, Add Minute button but removed from here for simplicity:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="SingleItemTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentTime.Hours}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="H"></TextBlock>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentTime.Minutes}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="M"></TextBlock>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentTime.Seconds}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="S"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Here is my ViewModel code which is injected in view:

```
public class Page1VM : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyTimer> _timersCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyTimer>();
      public Page1VM()
        {
            // sample code to simulate collection of timers
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var t = new MyTimer();
                t.TotalTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, i, 0);
                _timersCollection.Add(t);
                t.Start();
            }

        }

        public IList<MyTimer> TimersCollection
        {
            get { return _ghatikatimerscoll; }
        }

}
```

Here is ITimer Interace

```
public interface ITimer
    {
        bool Start();
        bool Stop();
        bool IsRunning { get; set; }
        void AddMinute();
    }
```

Its implementation

public class MyTimer : ViewModelBase, ITimer
{
    public TimeSpan TotalTimeSpan { private get; set; }

```
private readonly DispatcherTimer _myDispatcherTimer;
private TimeSpan _startTime;

public bool IsRunning { get; set; }
public MyTimer()
{
    _myDispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1) };
    _myDispatcherTimer.Tick += _myDispatcherTimer_Tick;
}

private TimeSpan _currentTime;
public TimeSpan CurrentTime
{
    get
    {
        return _currentTime;
    }
    set
    {
        _currentTime = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentTime");
    }
}

void _myDispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_myDispatcherTimer.IsEnabled)
    {
        var currenttime = TotalTimeSpan.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)) - (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay - _startTime);
        CurrentTime = currenttime;
    }
}

public bool Start()
{
    _startTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    if (_currentTime.TotalSeconds != 0)
    {
        // resuming after paused
        TotalTimeSpan = CurrentTime;
    }
    IsRunning = true;
    _myDispatcherTimer.Start();
    return true;
}

public bool Stop()
{
    _myDispatcherTimer.Stop();
    IsRunning = false;
    return true;
}

public void AddMinute()
{
    TotalTimeSpan = TotalTimeSpan.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 1));
}
```

}

Basically, I am displaying a collection of Timers on screen which updates itself. Each item in list has its own DispatcherTimer. User an click "Pause" button for each item to pause that particular timer. User can also click on "Add Minute" button which adds 1 minute to the particular item in collection.

Is this method efficient to update the UI constantly?

Comment: Rather than having one timer per item, you can declare one global timer that will update every item every second (actually, you should set a delay lower than a second or you may see some items skipping a second). It will be much more efficient than using x dispatcher timers

Comment: For that I need to place that timer in ViewModel. Right ? This also means that I need to use a ForEach loop over List. Also, which Timer object are you referring? MSDN link of that timer?

Comment: Just a clasical DispatcherTimer. And yes, you'd have to put it in the ViewModel and iterate with a foreach loop. You could also create a wrapper around the timer, define an event that will be triggered every second, and have all the items subscribe to that event, but I don't think it's worth the trouble

Comment: You mean the Observer pattern ?

Comment: Yes. It can be done easily by using events.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see an option to mark your reply as answer.

Comment: posting the comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than having one timer per item, you can declare one global dispatcher timer that will update every item every second (actually, you should set a delay lower than a second or you may see some items skipping a second). It will be much more efficient than using x dispatcher timers. You'd have to put it in the ViewModel and iterate with a foreach loop. You could also create a wrapper around the timer, define an event that will be triggered every second, and have all the items subscribe to that event, but I don't think it's worth the trouble.

Comment: I have accepted your answer however, how should i handle a case where i need to pause a particular timer if i use single DispatchTimer in ViewModel ?

Comment: @Nexus You can set a property "IsPaused" on your item, and check it when you iterate through them. Or think object, use the observer pattern, and have the item handle itself the "I am paused" logic when the timer's event is triggered

Comment: Thanks. Will see how this turns out.